# Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound al hacer un INSERT en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Me he encontrado con este problema al hacer un INSERT en MySQL. Los datos los recibo de un formulario que el usuario rellena (es un textarea para dejar comentarios en noticias). En este formulario tengo habilitados varios botones para poder publicar vídeos o tuits, y es en éste último caso en el que me está fallando.

El INSERT lo hago de esta forma:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios (tipologia, texto,texto_sin_etiquetas, quien_comenta, en_que_hilo) VALUES (
                                  'noticia',
                                  '$comentario',
                                  '$comentario_plano',
                                  '$quien_comenta',
                                  '$id_noticia'
                                )");
$statement->execute();
```

El funcionamiento es correcto salvo cuando se añade cualquier tuit. En ese caso me devuelve el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\noticia.php on line 106

He comprobado unas cuantas veces que todas las variables cuando se añade un tuit son correctas, y así es.

Si pruebo a publicar un comentario sin incluir un tuit, y posteriormente lo edito para incluir uno, se actualiza sin ningún problema.

**He conseguido que me funcione de esta forma:**

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE comentarios SET texto = :texto, texto_sin_etiquetas = :texto_sin_etiquetas, fecha_edicion = :fecha_edicion, editado_por = :editado_por, veces_editado = veces_editado + 1 WHERE ID = :ID");
$statement->execute(array(
                        ":texto" => $comentario,
                        ":texto_sin_etiquetas" => $comentario_plano,
                        ":fecha_edicion" => $fecha_total_actual,
                        ":editado_por" => $usuario['gamertag'],
                        ":ID" => $id_comentario
                      ));
```

Comment: Intenta quitar las comillas simples entre tus variables

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo Si quito las comillas no me funciona el INSERT de ninguna de las formas.

Comment: Si la columna `en_que_hilo` es de tipo numérica, la variable `$id_noticia` debería ir sin comillas simples. O sea, en un `INSERT` **los valores que son numéricos deben ir sin comillas simples todos**. Luego, como ya se ha dicho, te falta la `$` en el primer `VALUE` que intentas insertar (a no ser que en efecto la tipología sea `noticia` como tal; y, como también se ha dicho, convendría que des seguridad al código implementando consultas preparadas. Pero deberías decir si estás usando `PDO` o `mysqli`. Otra cosa que puede estar ocurriendo es que **¡alguna de tus variables tenga una coma `,`!**

Comment: @A.Cedano Si no me equivoco, uso PDO. He probado quitando las comillas y el problema persiste. Las comas no son ningún problema tampoco, he probado a publicar un comentario con comas y lo hace sin ningún problema. Entiendo que es problema de la consulta INSERT, porque en un UPDATE este problema no me ocurre.

Comment: Prueba a crear la consulta en una variable, imprímela, y prueba a ejecutarla directamente en el manejador de base de datos. Si da error, verifica si es el mismo error y muestra aquí la consulta (con datos). Me parece muy extraño. Y ya que hablas de que pasas los datos por filtros para sanearlos, puede que el problema sean esos filtros. No tienes que filtrar nada, sino usar consultas preparadas. Es lo único realmente seguro en estos casos, lo demás son mitos que se han ido creando. Hay pruebas de que aún saneando datos te pueden inyectar código malicioso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tras muchas pruebas he conseguido solucionarlo, pero sigo sin entender porqué no funciona de la forma en la que lo hago. La forma que sí me funciona es declarar primero las variables y declararlas cuando hago el execute(). Dejo una prueba de cómo me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que a la variable "noticia" le falta el `$` de las variables PHP, quedando tu consulta

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios (tipologia, texto,texto_sin_etiquetas, quien_comenta, en_que_hilo) VALUES (
                              '$noticia', // <= aquí está tu error
                              '$comentario',
                              '$comentario_plano',
                              '$quien_comenta',
                              '$id_noticia'
                            )");
$statement->execute();
```

Aunque te recomiendo que blindes tus variables por lo que en la otra respuesta indica que tienes un fallo de seguridad básico

Comment: No es un error, noticia no es una variable.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema en si no logro identificarlo, según veo todo esta correcto pero no a la vez, deberías tener una consulta preparada, si estas usando `PDO` *(no especificas esto en tu pregunta)* mi sugerencia seria la siguiente;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios (tipologia, texto,texto_sin_etiquetas, quien_comenta, en_que_hilo) 
VALUES (:tipologia,
        :comentario,
        :comentario_plano,
        :quien_comenta,
        :id_noticia)";

        $statement =$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement ->execute(array(":tipologia"=> "noticia", 
                                    ":comentario"=>$comentario,
                                    ":comentario_plano" => $comentario_plano, 
                                    ":quien_comenta" => $quien_comenta,
                                    ":id_noticia" => $id_noticia  ));
```

Ahora bien si usas `mysqli`:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios (tipologia, texto,texto_sin_etiquetas, quien_comenta, en_que_hilo) 
VALUES (:tipologia,
        :comentario,
        :comentario_plano,
        :quien_comenta,
        :id_noticia)");
    $statement ->bindParam(':tipologia', "noticia");
    $statement ->bindParam(':comentario', $comentario);
    $statement ->bindParam(':comentario_plano', $comentario_plano);
    $statement ->bindParam(':quien_comenta', $quien_comenta);
    $statement ->bindParam(':id_noticia', $id_noticia);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Te Recomiendo esto por cuestiones de seguridad, siempre deberías evitar pasar variables directas en tus consultas, nunca se sabe que viene dentro de ellas y evitamos posibles inyecciones `SQL`.

Usando los marcadores `:noticia` por ejemplo, nota los 2 puntos que estan como prefijo en la parte de `VALUES`

Puedes ampliar mas en esta pregunta de la comunidad:[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Es correcto lo que recomiendas en cuanto a **darle seguridad al código** para evitar ataques de inyección SQL. Pero esto funcionará sólo con `PDO`, no con `mysqli`. ¿El OP ha confirmado en alguna parte que está usando `PDO`?

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene razon, mi error. no me percate de esta parte. Gracias agregare algo de info.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo cierto es que no estoy seguro de si uso PDO, pero juraría que sí, aunque me dejas con la duda. En cuanto a la inyección de código, antes de meter nada en la base de datos paso las variables por filtros que he creado para que eso no ocurra, así que en ese sentido no debería haber mayor problema. Volviendo a la pregunta, sigue sin darme resultado, y lo curioso es que hago el mismo tipo de consulta en otro formulario que tengo para crear artículos, y ahí no me da ningún problema.